# Getting_init()_encoding_error while getting crypto data from coinbase

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am trying to get all historical data from coinbase for bitcoin from the start

of 2016 to present day. I know there are many approaches like using an API ,

scraping tables but I am trying to read the page as an HTML and still I am

getting the encoding the error.

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import numpy as np


# get market info for bitcoin from the start of 2016 to the current day

bitcoin_market_info = pd.read_html("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start=20130428&end="+time.strftime("%Y%m%d"))[0]
```

I get the error  as  `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'`

I have done other steps to prevent this error like checking

pd_version as it is greater than 0.15 and even using different encoding such as

```
encoding = 'utf-8',  encoding='big5hkscs'
```

I also checked htlm5lib and its already installed so can anyone tell me how to get data from this method only as it is used here in this article.

[crypto price prediction](https://dashee87.github.io/deep%20learning/python/predicting-cryptocurrency-prices-with-deep-learning/)

Comment: the code is working for me (pandas version 0.19.2, python version 3.6)

Comment: I have pandas version 20.3 and python version 3.6  but it still gives the error

Comment: what's your html5lib version ?

Comment: 0.999999999' is html5lib version

Comment: this was a buggy version. try upgrading html5lib, it should solve the problem.